# How to force PostgreSQL to use my index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id     SERIAL,
  factory_key    VARCHAR(60),
  relevant       BOOLEAN
)
Indexes:
"product_factory_key_key" btree (factory_key);
"product_factory_key_relevant_key" btree (factory_key, relevant) WHERE relevant = false;
"product_relevant_key" btree (relevant);
```

**Facts:**

1. We have about 100 million records in the `product` table
2. There are a small number of factories. For example, 1 factory could have 5 million products.
3. There are millions of factory keys
4. Only a small number of rows are NOT relevant for each factory. For example, there is a factory with 5 million products, has about 100 products that are NOT relevant.
5. However, There are million of rows of NOT relevant rows. As, the most common case is one factory key, 5 rows of products, and with maybe 2 rows of NOT relevant.

**This is the problem query:**

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE factory_key='some_product_key' AND relevant=false LIMIT 10;
```

Explain analyze:

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..23.06 rows=10 width=188) (actual time=2709.654..32252.961 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..7366785.34 rows=3194759 width=188) (actual time=2709.634..32252.904 rows=10 loops=1)
         Filter: ((NOT relevant) AND ((product_key)::text = 'some_product_key'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 449486
 Total runtime: 32253.150 ms
(5 rows)
```

**Problem:**

This is problematic because:

1. I believe the planner chose to use seq scan because there are so many rows that match this factory. (about 3.2 million rows match this factory or approx 3%)
2. However, because only a EXTREMELY small number of rows are NOT relevant. And I am looking for NOT relevant. A seq scan end up being extremely expensive.

I have already created an composite index `product_factory_key_relevant_key`, however it is not taking advantage of the index.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to force postgres to use the composite key: `product_factory_key_relevant_key`

`SET enable_seqscan=off`

Although, it is now using the index scan. It is actually still slower than a seqscan. (so I guess the planner was correct in doing a seq scan)

```
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..34.03 rows=10 width=188) (actual time=8.088..469974.692 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using product_factory_key_relevant_key on product  (cost=0.57..10689307.49 rows=3194776 width=188) (actual time=8.083..469974.655 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (relevant = false)
         Filter: ((NOT relevant) AND ((product_key)::text = 'some_product_key'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2205295
 Total runtime: 469974.820 ms
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Well, try it; you should indeed order columns in order of descending selectivity, so the first thing you should do is create the index. You'll probably want to `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` if you can't afford to block writes for a few hours.

Comment: @CraigRinger but this makes zero sense. I have created a specific composite index that specifically matches the condition. Why does the planner still not use my index. Hope you understand my frustration haha

Comment: Indexes aren't magic. In particular, index access requires lots of random I/O, so it can be a lot slower than a seqscan if random I/O costs are high and the index doesn't exclude most of the rows. So PostgreSQL may think that using the index is *more expensive* (i.e. slower) than the seqscan. If it's wrong, it's probably because your cost parameters don't reflect reality, though the planner certainly can mis-estimate costs. It could also be due to inaccurate statistics - show `explain analyze`.

Comment: BTW, the plan you showed is just `explain`. You need `explain analyze` to see issues with statistics. http://explain.depesz.com/s/jNot . See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @CraigRinger, please see my latest edit for explain analyze for both the original query and the query with seqscan turned off

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Overriding cost parameters

You can't ever force PostgreSQL to use a particular index, or totally prevent it from doing a seqscan.

However, you can tell it to avoid doing certain scan types if it possibly can, by setting the relevant `enable_` parameters to `off`. It's really a feature intended only for debugging.

For testing, try:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

if Pg can possibly use an index scan (or something else) it will.

You may also want to consider:

```
SET random_page_cost = 1.1
```

i.e. tell PostgreSQL that random I/O is only slightly more expensive than sequential I/O. This is usually true on systems with SSDs, or where most of the DB is cached in RAM. It will be more likely to choose an index in this case.

Of course, if your system's random I/O is actually more expensive, then using an index is likely to be slower.

### Selectivity, partial indexes

What you should really do is follow the advice you've already been given. Create the index in order of selectivity - if `relevant` is less common, use that. You can even go a step further and create a *partial index*:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name_blah ON tbl_name_blah (factory_key) WHERE (NOT relevant);
```

This index only contains values for `relevant = 'f'`. It can only be used for queries where the planner knows relevant will be false. On the other hand, it will be a *much* smaller, faster index.

### Statistics

You might also have inaccurate statistics, causing PostgreSQL to think value frequencies are different than they really are for your table. `explain analyze` will help show this.

You can also just `ANALYZE my_table` in case the stats are just out of date; if so, increase the frequency with which autovacuum runs because it's not keeping up.

If the stats are up to date but the planner is still making stats-based mis-estimations, increasing the statistics target for the table (see manual) and re-analyzing can help if it is actually a statistics mis-estimation problem.

### Versions

Older PostgreSQL versions tend to be less smart about cost estimation, query optimization, statistics, query execution methods, and pretty much everything else.

If you're not on the latest version, upgrade.

For example, 9.2's index-only scans would allow you to create a partial index

`(product_id, factory_key) WHERE (NOT relevant)`

and then run a query:

```
SELECT product_id, factory_key FROM my_table WHERE NOT relevant;
```

that should only read the index, with no heap access at all.

Comment: What is the difference between the example index you gave and the index I have which is: `"product_factory_key_relevant_key" btree (factory_key, relevant) WHERE relevant = false` ? Are they effectively the same thing?

Comment: OK, I missed that. Yes, they're pretty much the same; the `relevant` term in your index is totally pointless though, it just makes the index bigger and you should get rid of it. You really need to show `explain analyze` output of your query, both as-is with a seqscan, and with `enable_seqscan=off` to see what the planner thinks the next-cheapest plan is.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't have a test copy of the database, as the database is about 300GB. I have a subset of the data (about 10gb) but the planner behaves completely differently on a smaller database as a large one

Comment: Yep, you'll have to either do it live, or create a full size copy.

Comment: Since I have already have this index `"product_factory_key_key" btree (factory_key);` your partial index is still going to be helpful for my use case?

Comment: Yes, it will, because it only includes rows for which `relevant` is `false`. Partial indexes are very useful when you have one value that's very common and other much less common values; you can make an index that leaves out the very common values (for which using the index isn't useful anyway) so it only includes the values where the index is selective enough to be useful. I'd need to see the actual table statistics and the `explain analayze` of a query to say more confidently whether it'll be useful *in this case*, though.

Comment: please look at my latest edit. I think you will find the results very interesting. I turned off seqscan and forced it to use to composite index and the result was that it was substantially slower. I am not sure why that is the case yet. I will try you partial index tonight

Comment: Aah. What PostgreSQL version are you on?

Comment: one more requirement I have is that: I need to be able to do:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE factory_key IN ('some_product_key1','some_product_key2')  AND NOT relevant LIMIT 10;`

Would the partial index still be good for that purpose?

Comment: Think so; from memory Pg converts `IN` to an `AND` qual list internally. I recommend testing to see.

Comment: The interesting thing is that when doing WHERE IN, the composite key is cheaper than the partial index. (according to explain)

Comment: Ok got it to work. This is now substantially faster with the partial index. You, my friend, are a hero to me.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, the problem in your query is the `$1`. I imagine this means you're using a prepared statement because you've read somewhere that it's best practice.

This is actually bad, because PG cannot know in advance if the cardinality of the criteria you're using is high or low. As such, it needs to pick a plan that'll fit most cases. If some values are all over the place in such a way that the left-most part of your btree index is useless, it'll have very good reasons to seq scan.

In contrast, if you run the query without preparing it first, it'll plan base on the values you've passed and pick the best plan *for that specific value*. Therefor, consider running the same query *without* preparing it, if it begins to use your existing index, you're in this pathological use-case.

If not, what Craig said... In particular the partial index.

Comment: On newer versions, Pg parameterizes plans, and will re-check to see whether it should generate a specialized plan or use the generic plan. So it's less of a problem these days.

Comment: Sweet. I wasn't aware of that. :-)

Comment: Tom added it to 9.2, see git commit e2fa76d80ba571d4de8992de6386536867250474